# EXCEL VBA: get data from range

Tags: excel, vba, range

I have report that contains 500 thousand cells of data (from A to M).

I need to summarize this data.

example FROM:

no. date    action  time

```
112256  07/Jul/2014 Done    1:00:00 AM  
112256  07/Jul/2014 Done    1:15:00 AM  
112256  07/Jul/2014 Done    1:18:00 AM  
112256  07/Jul/2014 Adjusted    1:35:00 AM  
112256  07/Jul/2014 Adjusted    1:39:00 AM  
112256  07/Jul/2014 Finished    1:57:00 AM  
112387  07/Jul/2014 Done    3:01:00 AM  
112387  07/Jul/2014 Adjusted    3:33:00 AM  
112387  07/Jul/2014 Adjusted    3:45:00 AM  
112387  07/Jul/2014 Finished    4:57:00 AM
```

no: date    done    adjusted    finished

```
112256  07/Jul/2014 1:00:00 AM  1:39:00 AM  1:57:00 AM
112387  07/Jul/2014 3:01:00 AM  3:45:00 AM  4:57:00 AM
```

Problem:

as you see "no." is ascending, and every "no." can have from 1 up to 50 values (actions taken). 
When sumarizing I need only 1 "no." (identifying the part been made), 1 "date" (when), and 3 actions times "the first when it was done, the last when it was adjusted, and - the one and only - finished"

I got caught up on this, I was thinking how to select range with the same "no." and then search in that range for first done, last adjusted and finished, but I was not able to work properly in one range. I have nothing at the moment, and this is only the little part, but a proper start I believe is a way to great success.
Thank you for your answers.

Comment: What do you want to summarize? I know the data, but do you want, say, a count of the done, adjusted, or finished? I'm not sure what you are trying to do.

Also, you haven't included any code that you may or may not have tried? Have you tried writing the code at all yourself?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the right place to "request" code..

Comment: @tannman357 hello, as with every action an additional line adds up to the report, I need to summarize it, by getting the time only of the first done, last adjusted, and finished action.
Lets say it was adjusted 34 times, same no. part, so I need when summarizing get only last adjusted (that saves 34 lines!) as every line contains same data, just a different time when i tas adjusted.

In the end:
no. - one details number
date - date when done
done - time when first done
adjusted - time when last adjusted
finished - when finished

Comment: For i = 3 To n
 
    If report.Range("A" & i) = report.Range("A" & b) Then
    b = b + 1
    Else
   
     For a = i To b
    
       reps = Data.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
       no = report.Range("A" & a).Value
       Data.Range("A" & reps).Value = no
   
     Next a
    
    b = b + 1
    End If

Next i

Comment: Oh that makes sense. You really just need some loops. Btw, I can't read code in the comments at all...

Comment: @tanman357 what I have is not working.
What I need is to find when the detail now shows first and last, and then put another for to work in that range and export needed data to other worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Pivot table is the answer, but you'll need to add a helper column first.

Assuming your data above is in columns A:D, in `E2` enter the following formula and copy down (down-side to this method is recalculation could be very slow). I put `Combined` as the column header in `E1`. You can rename as needed.

```
=IF($C2="Finished","Keep",IF(AND($C2="Done",$D2=MIN(IF(A:A=$A2,IF(C:C=$C2,D:D)))),"Keep",IF(AND($C2="Adjusted",$D2=MAX(IF(A:A=$A2,IF(C:C=$C2,D:D)))),"Keep","No")))
```

This is array formula so you'll need to press `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ENTER` to get it to work properly.

What this does is show keep for all `Finished` items, all the first `Done` items, and all the last `Adjusted` items for each `No.`

Then create a pivot table, and you'll put the following items in the Pivot Table areas:

1. Report Filter: New `Combined` column
2. Column Labels: `Action` column
3. Row Labels: `No.` column, followed by `Date` column
4. Values: `Time` column

Now to format the pivot table.

1. In the values area of the pivot table, change the `Value Field Settings` to `Sum`
2. Filter the `Combined` report filter to only include items that have `Keep`
3. In the Pivot Table Design tab of the ribbon select Subtotals and `Do Not Show Subtotals`
4. In the Pivot Table Design tab of the ribbon select Grand Totals and 
   `Off for Rows and Columns`
5. In the Pivot Table Design tab of the ribbon select Report Layout and `Show in Tabular Form`
6. In the Pivot Table Design tab of the ribbon select Report Layout and `Repeat All Item Labels`

Your end result should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Hello!
Summarizing this data is just first step out of ten! I will be able to act on myself after this step - I will need to check how many items where made not on time, and what is the reason, I have not pasted the full excel data, because there is really a lot (A to M columns).
I need to understand how I need to get the range for data, for example - I find the same detail number, and i need to get range for it for example detail no 157722 range 19457 - 19467 (data contains more than 500k rows) - so okey there are 10 rows and actions made with this detail.

Comment: So for i = 1 to n, I would need to find the row when first this number showed and last, then I would add another for, which I would run through these 10 rows, finding the first done, last adjusted and finished and exporting them in one row to other sheet.

Comment: Hey that's great, but to help others, I would parse your steps into different questions. If you know your starting point and your end point, figure out what you need to do then post different questions where you get stuck. Expanding on your question in the comments won't help you or others get to your solution.